# Can we run the jar in the GCP VM from the cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Can we run the jar in the GCP VM from the cloud function-

We thaught of deploying the jar in cloud function directly and running from there but we encountered the execution time out issues, so Is there any way that we can just to trigger the jar file in GCP VM from cloud function

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to run a process in background, for a long time? What's the max duration?

Answer (score 0):

If the only purpose of the VM is to run this process I would:

- [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) calls a Cloud Function.
- The Cloud Function starts a [VM with a startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) that runs the jar process, and shuts down.

If you need to pass arguments to the script, you can do it using instance metadata when you create the instance (or while it is already running).

You can also have a look at this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/start-stop-compute-engine-instance-from-cloud-function-bf9ae5199609) (which is not supported by google). There you will find how you can  start and stop instances using cloud functions.